# "Occupation" field on IRS Form 1040

Tags: united-states, income-tax, irs

At the bottom of IRS Form 1040 and its relatives, there is a field for "Occupation".

- I can think of a lot of different words I could use to describe my occupation.  Are there any requirements or guidelines for how I should decide what to put?
- How does the IRS use this information, if at all?

[This forum discussion](http://www.accountantforums.com/threads/occupation-on-form-1040.12979/page-2) suggests the answers are "it really doesn't matter" and "they don't", but it doesn't seem authoritative.

The only use I can imagine is that if you write down an occupation that typically has a very high income ("railroad tycoon", "oil baron", "international crime lord"), and then report a tiny income, it might make you more likely to be audited.

(Note: I am not referring to the "Principal Business" field on Schedule C, lines A and B.)

Comment: In the 2016 1040NR, the field actually says "Occupation in the United States" which is even more confusing, if I have an occupation but it is not in the United States. What do they care when I stopped beating my wife??

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't generally matter, and I'm not sure if it is in fact in use by the IRS other than for general statistics (like "this year 20% of MFJ returns were with one spouse being a 'homemaker'").

They may be able to try and match the occupation and the general levels and types of income, but for self-employed there's a more precise and reliable field on Schedule C and for employees they don't really need to do this since everything is reported on W2 anyway. So I don't think they even bother or give a lot of value to such a metric.

So yes, I'm joining the non-authoritative "doesn't matter" crowd.

Comment: I don't even know that I put down a consistent answer before I used tax software to complete the forms.  Was I a programmer, computer programmer, software developer?

Comment: I use "underwater basket weaver".